# For-Loop and LINQ's deferred execution don't play well together

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop, .net-4.0

The title suggests that i've already an idea what's going on, but i cannot explain it. I've tried to order a `List<string[]>` dynamically by each "column", beginning with the first and ending with the minimum `Length` of all arrays.

So in this sample it is `2`, because the last `string[]` has only two elements:

```
List<string[]> someValues = new List<string[]>();
someValues.Add(new[] { "c", "3", "b" });
someValues.Add(new[] { "a", "1", "d" });
someValues.Add(new[] { "d", "4", "a" });
someValues.Add(new[] { "b", "2" });
```

Now i've tried to order all by the first and second column. I could do it statically in this way:

```
someValues = someValues
    .OrderBy(t => t[0])
    .ThenBy(t => t[1])
    .ToList();
```

But if i don't know the number of "columns" i could use this loop(that's what I thought):

```
int minDim = someValues.Min(t => t.GetLength(0));  // 2
IOrderedEnumerable<string[]> orderedValues = someValues.OrderBy(t => t[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < minDim; i++)
{
    orderedValues = orderedValues.ThenBy(t => t[i]);
}
someValues = orderedValues.ToList();  // IndexOutOfRangeException
```

But that doesn't work, it fails with an `IndexOutOfRangeException` at the last line. The debugger tells me that `i` is `2` at that time, so the for-loop condition seems to be ignored, `i` is already `== minDim`.

Why is that so? What is the correct way for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the same problem as lots of people had with `foreach` loops pre C# 5.

```
orderedValues = orderedValues.ThenBy(t => t[i]);
```

The value of `i` will not be evaluated until you call `.ToList()` at which point it is 2 since that's the exit condition of the for loop.

You can introduce a new local variable inside the for-loop to fix it:

```
for (int i = 1; i < minDim; i++)
{
    var tmp = i;
    orderedValues = orderedValues.ThenBy(t => t[tmp]);
}
```

---

For more information you could take a look at Eric Lippert's blog post about [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

Comment: _"The "for" loop will not be changed."_ So even if i'm still using .NET 4 this issue is also related to people which are already using C#5.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the problems with the breaking change of foreach-loops in C# 5. In a way they now behave differently than for-loops.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably happening because the value of `i` is not closed within the loop - when the loop exits, `i` will have a value of `2` and *then* `t[i]` will be evaluated because of deferred execution.

One solution is to create a closing variable within the loop:

```
int minDim = someValues.Min(t => t.GetLength(0));  // 2
IOrderedEnumerable<string[]> orderedValues = someValues.OrderBy(t => t[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < minDim; i++)
{
    var x = i;
    orderedValues = orderedValues.ThenBy(t => t[x]);
}
someValues = orderedValues.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, i've accepted Dirks because he mentioned `foreach loops pre C# 5` and (now) the link to E. Lippert's blog which explains all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Fair enough - glad you got it working.